# comfiture and discomfiture - etymology

Tags: etymology

> **discomfiture**
>
> *anxious embarrassment*
>
> **comfiture**
>
> *a candy containing a nut or piece of fruit.*

Are these two "false friends", words seeming to be related but of completely different origin, or do they share a common etymology?

If so, when did they diverge in meaning - what was the original word that diverged in one direction to sweet foodstuffs, and in other to negative feelings?

Comment: Brief answer: both come from Latin _(dis)+cum+facere_, '(un)+with+make'. Latin _conficere_ means 'put together'; that's the source of _comfit(ure),_ and of _confection_ (_confectus_ is the p.pple of _conficere_), all referring to prepared sweet and treats. The opposite of 'put together' is 'take apart, destroy', and that's the source of _discomfit(ure). -ure_ is a derivational suffix that attaches to verbs, and _discomfit_ is a verb. All of these words are borrowed from French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the International French-English and English-French dictionary Editorial Critic of French Pronunciations PAUL PASSY:

The words 'discomfit' and 'descomfiture' essentially have the same definition, and synonyms                                                                                                                                                                             Par example:

**discomfit**: défaire,  dé-route; disperser; vaincre; dérouter, déconfire

**descomfiture**: défaite, déroute, dé-confiture                                                                                                                                                                                   The last synonym, dé-confiture is French to get out of a jam, and in French jam archaically meant candied fruit
[Comfiture](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/186577/comfiture) and [confiture](http://encyclopedie_universelle.fracademic.com/33783/confiture) have the same meaning